# angular $location,$route lifecycle events fired off twice when browser encodes url

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, url-parameters

using angular 1.2.10

> UPDATED: issue is also occurring in latest legacy(1.2.21) and beta
>   versions(1.3.0-beta.17

I provided a simplified example that demonstrates the issue I am encountering below

Basically, the behavior that I am seeing and trying to prevent, is that when my app loads a route whose url is 
automatically encoded by the browser (e.g. because there are **spaces** or **+'s** in the parameter values), I am seeing the **$location** and **$route** service lifecycle events
getting fired off twice.
Using the example provided below the easiest way to duplicate this behavior is to load the app and append the following params:

```
?message=test val

?message=test+val
```

If you look at the console output you'll see the first example causes the **$locationChangeStart** and **$locationChangeSuccess** handler to be fired off twice.
Based on the documentation I believe angular is monitoring the address bar for changes and I am guessing its firing off these events for the unencoded url and then again
once its encoded.

Is there a way to prevent this?

NOTE: I also noticed that despite a **'+'** being a valid substitute for a **space** in a parameter value, the resulting value retains the '+'; i.e. ?message=test+val will be rendered as 'test+val' not 'test val'.  There is an existing [ticket](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3042#issuecomment-41274700) for this issue.

UPDATE: I opened up this [ticket](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8368) with the angular team.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html id="ng-app" data-ng-app="test">
    <head>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
        <script>
            'use strict';
            angular.module('test', ['ngRoute'])
                .config(function($routeProvider) {
                    $routeProvider.when('/',
                            {
                                template: '{{data.params}}',
                                controller:'TestCtrl',
                                resolve:{params: function($route) {return $route.current.params;}}
                            })
                })
                .run(function($rootScope) {
                    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart',function(event, next, current){
                        console.log(event.name,'current=' + current,'next=' + next);
                    });
                    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess',function(event, next, current){
                        console.log(event.name,'current=' + current,'next=' + next,'\n');
                    });
                })
                .controller('TestCtrl',function($scope,params){
console.log('Inside TestCtrl');
$scope.data={params:params};});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem. In my case it was while trying to handle history, and for some reason the second lifecycle was clearing my fragment identifiers, so the partial page refresh wasn't working.

The only way I could get around it was by looking at **$location.search()** to see if it was a valid change and calling **event.preventDefault()** in the **$locationChangeStart** handler if it wasn't. This prevents it from continuing to the **$locationChangeSuccess** handler. In your case, could you check **location.url()** to see if the url has been encoded yet? If not, just kill the cycle and wait for the encoded url to trigger.

I know this is a hack, but it fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I had initially tried that approach, but for some reason once that first $locationChangeStart is prevented, the second one is not fired off,despite the address bar getting encoded. I've opened up this [ticket](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8368) with the angular team.